# validation in php form not working

Tags: php

Hi I am strugling with the validation of my form. I have build in teh code from w3school and went through it to check the tas and couldn't find any mistake. This is my first php form and am a real beginner. Can someoe help to look through my php.

```
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
    $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
    if (empty($_POST["name"]))
    {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
    else
    {$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
     {$nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";}
     }
     *
     *
     *
     *
     *
     function test_input($data)
     {
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
     }
     // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
     $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
     $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

     // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <mpa@giz-zuerich.ch>' . "\r\n";
    //$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

    // send email
    mail($strEmpfaenger,$strSubject,$mitteilung,$headers);
    header('Location: http://www.giz-zuerich.ch/_private/sites/danke.html');
    ?>
```

My html code looks like this:

```
    <form action="../php/terminform.php" method="post">
       <dl>
    <dt><label for="name" >Name</label></dt>
    <dd><input type="text" name="name" value="">
        <span class="error"> *<?php echo $nameErr;?></span></dd>
      </dl>
     </form>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What errors do you get?

Comment: no errors Form sent but without message

Answer (score 0):

the code missing `'}'` of `if()` check it

Comment: I have checked the '}'. None is missing